# Function name resolution depending on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, argument-dependent-lookup

Came across the following task in a test:

```
#include <iostream> using namespace std;

template<typename T> void adl(T) {   cout << "T"; }

struct S { };

template<typename T> void call_adl(T t) {   adl(S());   adl(t); }

void adl(S) {   cout << "S"; }

int main () {   call_adl(S()); }
```

The question is which functions will be called.
There is also an explanation that the name of the function which does not depend on a template argument is resolved at the time of template definition, while the name of those which do depend on a template argument is resolved when a template argument is known. Well, what's the difference between these "times"?

Answer (score 6):

Nice question. It will call the template version first, and the non-template version second. [[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8ac353a16fff9c5)

The reason is, as the explanation says, that in this expression:

```
adl(S());
```

the name `adl` is resolved as soon as the parser encounters it. Notice that at this time, the `adl(S)` function is no yet declared. So the name must resolve to the function template.

The other expression:

```
adl(t);
```

is different, because it depends on the the template parameter `T` (which is the type of `t`). Therefore, the resolution of the name is postponed until instantiation time, when the argument for `T` is known. Instantiation happens in `main`, *after* the declaration of `adl(S)`. Therefore, this call resolves to the non-template version.

Comment: Do you mean that it will call the template version first and non-template version second(it looks like there is typo in the first sentence)?

Comment: Note that msvc doesn't respect the standard here (and call the non-template version twice).

Comment: I know only the rule that a regular function has precedence before template function specialization. Is there the same for just (not specialized) template?

Comment: @VladimirLenin You can't call a function template; in the end, you always call a function template specialisation - even if it's an implicit one. So the rule you know covers this.